# Error while trying to deserialize the Amazon Textract output

Tags: system.text.json, amazon-textract

I am defining the OutputConfig property of the StartDocumentTextDetectionRequest in order to save the Amazon Textract json result in my own custom bucket.

The problem that I have is that I try to deserialize the json file to the DetectDocumentTextResponse type, I am getting the following exception:

System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to Amazon.Textract.BlockType. Path: $.Blocks[0].BlockType | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 30.'

How should I do to make the deserialization to work properly, because the json file is valid.

Comment: We'll be able to help faster if you provide example json and the classes you're trying to deserialise to.

Comment: @tymtam I'm facing the same problem being unable to desterilize Textract response in my s3 bucket. Since the JobId is expired after 7 days I cant find another way to read the result other than resubmitting it back to textract. trying to deserialize into GetDocumentTextDetectionResponse